# My form is not showing which i have created under subcategory in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created a menu in subcategory and created the form in phtml file when I click on the subcategory link the form is not showing.It is showing the page not found.Please anyone help me.

In admin catalog->Manage categories->add sub category in this I had created the link.

[image]

My form

```
  <form action="http://www.labwise.in/devel/zensearch/order" id="bookingtest" method="post">
   <div class="fieldset">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="testname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Test Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="testname" name="testname" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Test Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="field"> 

            <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $_GET['city']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label for="location" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Location') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" value="<?php echo $_GET['location']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Location') ?>" />
                </div>

        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="cname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="field">
         <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
   <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?></span></span></button>
   </div>


   </form>
```

CMS code In content:

```
        <p>{{block type='core/template' name='quickservice' template="quickservice/form.phtml"'}}</p>
```

Comment: can you add your code  for better understanding of question.

Comment: I have edited my question.Please review it.

Comment: did you work on custom module? or you want to show the  only the form.

Comment: Just I want to show the above from

Comment: posted the solution may be work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the cms page and call your form.phtml file

```
{{block type="core/template" template="test/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Yes.I had created that also but it is showing page not found

Comment: did you preview the cms page directly it show page or not ?

Comment: Yes,When I see the preview it is showing error message as page is not found.

Comment: are you created the cms page or not? add only some text and see it show or not?

Comment: yes,I created the cms page and seen the preview the preview it self showing the error message.

Comment: did you apply security patches?

Comment: Applied but it has not worked fine.So,I reverted to old

Comment: add your cms code here too

Comment: Added the code.Please review it.

Comment: you added the single quote extra add this code in you cms content
<p>{{block type='core/template' name='quickservice' template="quickservice/form.phtml"}}</p>

Comment: Added but it is showing same error page.

Comment: clear ur cache too..

Comment: Cleared the cache but it is showing same error

Comment: Can you please come again

Comment: http://www.labwise.in/devel/index.php/quick-service.html this is working check it

Comment: yes it is working

Comment: What you have changed

Comment: problem with ur admin setting in web tab Search Engines Optimization set to no or add htacess file.

Comment: But my another tools module is showing error page after changing this.Why??

Comment: simply add your previous .htaccess file and it will perfectly